# Sum of orders per customer ID

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

So, I have two tables, `customers` and `orders` and I want to get all orders associated with a customer.

The tables look like this:

**Customers**

```
customer_no   order_no
       1027       V327
       1027       V391
       1028       V400
etc..
```

**Orders**

```
order_no article1 article2 size order_date quantity
    V327    Jeans    Black   36   20150101        2
    V327    Shirt     Blue    L   20150101        1
    V327    Shirt    White    L   20150101        2
    V391    Jeans      Red   34   20150202        3
    V400    Shirt    Green   32   20150226        2
etc..
```

Now, I currently use the following query, but it is dog slow and I just know I'm approaching this wrongly. I feel like it should be possible to solve this with a join somewhere, but for the life of mine, I just cannot figure this one out.

```sql
SELECT article1, article2, size, order_date, SUM(quantity)
FROM orders
WHERE order_no IN (
    SELECT order_no
    FROM customers
    WHERE customer_no = '1027'
)
GROUP BY article1, article2, size, order_date, SUM(quantity)
```

The output for customer 1027 is (and should be):

```
article1 article2 size order_date SUM(quantity)
   Jeans    Black   36   20150101             2
   Shirt     Blue    L   20150101             1
   Shirt    White    L   20150101             2
   Jeans      Red   34   20150202             3
```

Does anyone have a better way of solving this? Performance is my main issue here.

Comment: Can you change the data model to normalize it? I'm wondering why `order_no` appears in the `customers` table.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I only inherited this structure, and I really really do not want to break everything built on top of this database, so no, sadly.

Comment: ...I dunno if this is just some quirk of MySQL, but `GROUP BY` an aggregate function (`SUM(quantity)`) looks *extremely* wrong to my eye.

Comment: @jpmc26 that should've been `size` rather than `SUM(quantity)`. I have no idea what brainfart of mine caused me to write that in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: You have `size` in the list, though. If it's not supposed to be there, then it looks to me like you just copied your output column list and forgot to delete it off the end. No harm. Just glad we got it cleared up.

Comment: `Order_no` is in no way a property of a Customer and therefore has nothing to do in the Customers table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying a `JOIN` sounds pretty easy

```
SELECT article1, article2, size, order_date, SUM(quantity)
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.order_no = customers.order_no
WHERE customers.customer_no = '1027'
GROUP BY article1, article2, size, order_date, SUM(quantity)
```

You should note that nested `SELECT` statements in a `WHERE` clause almost always lead to bad performance.

---

Also that kind of unnormalized data model looks weird, but there may be good reasons why to keep `order_no` and `customer_no` pairs in a single association table. May be its just bad naming, something like `customers_orders` might probably have been a better choice.

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully. With regard to the data model, that was my horrible attempt to simplify and translate some Dutch to English, in Dutch it's _klant_bestellingen_, so pretty much customer orders. Please forgive me for my incompetent translation :).

Comment: @N.Wouda De nada. Considering my SQL fu is pretty rusty nowadays, I was wondering if my proposal would work for you at all ;-).

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that an `INNER JOIN` would be better:

```
SELECT customers.article1
    , customers.article2
    , customers.size
    , customers.order_date
    , SUM(customers.quantity)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers
    ON customers.order_no = orders.order_no
WHERE customers.customer_no = '1027'
GROUP BY customers.article1
    , customers.article2
    , customers.size
    , customers.order_date
    , SUM(customers.quantity)
```

Also, the `SUM(customers.quantity)` in the `GROUP BY` looks really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `INNER JOIN` would solve your issue:

```
SELECT 
 orders.article1, 
 orders.article2,
 orders.size, 
 orders.order_date, 
 SUM(orders.quantity) AS [Quantity]
FROM 
 orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.order_no = customers.order_no
WHERE 
 customer.cust_no = 1027
GROUP BY 
 orders.article1, 
 orders.article2, 
 orders.size, 
 orders.order_date
```

The difference is that I removed the `SUM(orders.quantity)` from the `GROUP BY` since it doesn't belong in that statement. I corrected @BCdotWEB since he used the `customers` table and not the `orders` table when calling columns. Also, I am not sure how the voted answer worked as there should have been an error due to the `SUM(orders.quantity)` being used in the `Group By`.